# Help me understand the jumps of a càdlàg function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a càdlàg function (right-continuous with left limits). I keep reading that $f$ can jump infinitely, but countably, many times on $[0,1]$. How is that possible? By right-continuity, jumps must be "separated", that is, there exists an open set around each jump that does not include another jump. This must imply that the number of jumps must be finite, right? What am I missing?

For instance, how can a càdlàg function jump at every rational number in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Consider the set $\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. Each element is isolated in an open interval, but the set is infinite.

Comment: Nobody said it 'can jump at _every_ rational number'.. :) Based on the @Karl comment, consider the function 

$$[0;1] \ni x\mapsto \frac 1n \text{ iff } x\in \left[\frac 1{n+1}; \frac 1n\right), n\in\mathbb N$$

Comment: PS. Of course the definition above should define the domain as a left-open interval $(0;1]$ and possiby add $f(0) = 0.$

Comment: Thank you all, I see what I missed.

Comment: Inspired by this talk I have added a relevant graph to Wikipedia: [Discrete probability distribution with a countable set of discontinuities.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Discrete_probability_distribution_with_a_countable_set_of_discontinuities.svg), which you can see in en-wiki [Càdlàg # Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g#Definition) section.